# Parentheses or just Quotes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, syntax

Okay, so I've known about this for like 600 years now, but I've only *just now* cared to wonder why.

Why, in C# can we assign to a string like this?:

```
string f = "u";
```

AND ALSO:

```
string n = ("ny");
```

Is there any difference? I've not noticed any, but I always use ""; without the parentheses.

Comment: How about "(3+2)" vs "3+2"? Gonna open a question about that too? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is not any difference. The parenthesis can be used in any expression to explicitly define precedence of the operations. For your simple case, the expression is the string itself, so there is no need for the parenthesis. There is no difference in the compiled IL.